# @PreAuthorization annotation with custom method doesn't work

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to call a custom method using Spring @PreAuthorize at the method level in the service layer, but my custom method is not being called. My code:

spring-application-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dice" />
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Component definition:

```
@Component(value="authorizationService")
public class AuthorizationService implements AuthorizationServiceInt {
    public boolean test(String key) {
        logger.debug("AUTHORIZATION CALLED: " + key);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller that calls the util class:

```
@InjectParam
CustomerUtil customerUtil;

@GET
@Path("/{customerId}/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getCustomerInfo(@PathParam("customerId") Integer customerId,
    @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam("fields") String partialResponseFields) {

    logger.debug("getCustomerInfo called: id: " + customerId + ", uriInfo = " + uriInfo.getPath());
    try {
        return buildOKResourceResponse(new CustomerActionResource(customerUtil.getCustomerInfo(uriInfo, customerId)),partialResponseFields);
```

Usage of the component:

```
@InjectParam
AuthorizationService svc;

@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.test('special')")
public Customer getCustomerInfo(UriInfo uriInfo, Integer id) {
    logger.debug("svc: " + svc.hasPermission("x"));
    return populateCustomerInfo(uriInfo, PstUserModelServiceUtil.getPstUserModelByPstUserId(id));
}
```

I included the InjectParam just to make sure that the AuthorizationService class was being recognized by Spring. And sure enough, the 'AUTHORIZATION CALLED' debug statement appears when I call via the injected class, but does not appear when called via the @PreAuthorization call.

My spring jars:

```
spring-aop-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.5.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-solr-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-oauth2-1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
```

What am I doing wrong? I have interfaces on both the component class and the class using the component as I read that with aop, the fact that Spring decorates the impl class that an interface is needed for spring to see the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security works by creating a proxy of the class that is annotated with the security annotation (i.e. `@PreAuthorize`). In order for it to be proxied, the class that has the security annotation must be created by Spring and any invocations must be made on the instance created by Spring.

Verify that the class with `public Customer getCustomerInfo` is created by Spring and not in some other way.

Comment: I updated the original post with the Spring controller call to the getCustomerInfo() method. And I'm sort of veering off into unrelated territory, but we had to use InjectParam to "fix" an exception being thrown when trying to use Autowired. Is the use of the jersey InjectParam to inject the CustomerUtil object the problem? In that the object isn't being created by Spring when using that annotation instead of Autowired?

Comment: Thanks! I believe that the '@InjectParam CustomerUtil' was the problem. We had plans to move the CustomerUtil class into the service layer, inject the bean via spring-context.xml, and then use a servlce locator class to find the bean. So I went ahead and did that and once I did (and allowed Spring to create the bean) PreAuthorize annotation began firing like a charm.